# Send mail/save draft from Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I wonder if there is a way to override Django admin's submit_line buttons for a specific model, so that instead of showing the save & save and add another options they show send mail or save draft and actually work...
Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the admin's submit_row template tag does not follow the pattern for searching for templates: admin/app_label/model/submit_line.html

The bug is reported here with a patch to fix it, but seems to be waiting for the thumbs up from the django core devs: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11974